# Computing structure tensors

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra

As far as I understand, the *structure tensor* is:

$$
M = \sum_{(x,y) \in W} \begin{bmatrix} I_x^2 & I_xI_y \\ I_xI_y & I_y^2 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \sum_{(x,y) \in W} I_x^2 & \sum_{(x,y) \in W} I_xI_y \\ \sum_{(x,y) \in W} I_xI_y & \sum_{(x,y) \in W} I_y^2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I compute $I_x^2, I_y^2, I_xI_y$. I used **Hadamard product** for compute $I_x^2, I_y^2, I_xI_y$. But if I use **Hadamard product**, I will get $\det(M) = 0$. I'm stuck in here for too long. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know what $I_x,I_y$ are? If so, I don't see any difficulty, beyond programming, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Also, are $I_x,I_y$ scalars or matrices?

Comment: Where does Hadamard product come in? It's not there in the formulas.

Comment: I had already compute $I_x, I_y$ which are gradient of $I$ following x and y axis. $I_x, I_y$ is matrices

Comment: Hadamard product is usually the wrong operation to apply on matrices; though in this particular case, $I_xI_y$ is a bit strange if you use the usual product, unless the two matrices commute.

Comment: This is harris detection, i had already compute $I_x, I_y$ from origin image. I'm trying to find $I_x^2$ what it is.

Comment: My understanding is that $I_x,I_y$ are scalars.

Comment: If $W$ contains a single point, then $\det(M) = I_x^2 I_y^2 - (I_x I_y)^2 = 0$. So you need at least two points.

Comment: Sorry,my misunderstanding. $I_x, I_y$ are just scalars. But if $I_x,I_y$ are scalars. I'll get $det(M)=0$, $tr(M) = \sum_{(x,y)\in W } (I_x^2 + I_y^2)$, and $W$ contains more than single point. Why when $W$ contains more than contains more than single point $det(M) \nequiv 0$?

Comment: I agree with your trace formula, but not with your formula for the determinant. Suppose for example that the first point has $(I_x,I_y) = (1,0)$, and the second one has $(I_x,I_y) = (0,1)$ (and there are no other points). Then $M$ is the identity matrix, which has nonzero determinant.

Comment: But $det(M) = \sum_{(x,y) \in W} (I_x^2 I_y^2 - (I_xI_y)^2)$ still equal 0?

Comment: I just gave you a counterexample. Your formula is simply wrong. Try it with my counterexample to see why.

Comment: First, i have $(I_x,I_y)=(1,0)$, i have $$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Second, i have $(I_x,I_y)=(0,1)$ , at now i have $$M =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$. What am i misunderstanding?. Btw, thank you for help me alot.

Comment: The formula to the determinant is just not what you wrote. You're putting the sum in the wrong place. It's not true in general that $\det(A+B) = \det A + \det B$.

Comment: (Nice example how a comprehensive answer might not give the best learning experience.)

Comment: finally, i got it. thank you.